# Best way to remove an element from a List inside of a Map in Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am using [Facebook's Immutable.js](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) to speed up my React application to take advantage of the [PureRender mixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html). One of my data structures is a `Map()` and one of the keys in that map has a `List<Map>()` as its value. What I'm wondering is, not knowing the index of the item I want to remove from the `List()`, what is the best way to go about removing it? So far I have come up with the below. Is this the best (most efficient) way?

```
// this.graphs is a Map() which contains a List<Map>() under the key "metrics"
onRemoveMetric: function(graphId, metricUUID) {
    var index = this.graphs.getIn([graphId, "metrics"]).findIndex(function(metric) {
        return metric.get("uuid") === metricUUID;
    });
    this.graphs = this.graphs.deleteIn([graphdId, "metrics", index]);
}
```

(I have considered moving the `List<Map>()` to a `Map()` itself since each element in the list has a UUID, however, I'm not at that point yet.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use [`Map.filter`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/filter):

```
onRemoveMetric: function(graphId, metricUUID) {
  this.graphs = this.graphs.setIn([graphId, "metrics"],
    this.graphs.getIn([graphId, "metrics"]).filter(function(metric) {
      return metric.get("uuid") !== metricUUID;
    })
  )
}
```

From a performance point of view switching to a Map would probably be more efficient, as this code (like yours) has to iterate over the elements in the list.

Comment: Certainly much more concise than mine! And yes, the solutions you and I both have, I don't think it can be made more efficient without switching to a `Map`.

Comment: you can use [updateIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/updateIn) now, instead of repeating`this.graphs.getIn([graphId, "metrics"])`.

Answer (score 6):

Using [updateIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/updateIn) as suggested by @YakirNa this will look like below.

*ES6:*

```
  onRemoveMetric(graphId, metricUUID) {
    this.graphs = this.graphs.updateIn([graphId, 'metrics'],
      (metrics) => metrics.filter(
        (metric) => metric.get('uuid') !== metricUUID
      )
    );
  }
```

*ES5:*

```
  onRemoveMetric: function(graphId, metricUUID) {
    this.graphs = this.graphs.updateIn([graphId, "metrics"], function(metrics) {
      return metrics.filter(function(metric) {
        return metric.get("uuid") !== metricUUID;
      });
    });
  }
```