# How to delete an element from an array which is inside an object in ImmutableJS

Tags: javascript, immutability, immutable.js

if i have an object like so:

```
var fruitList = Immutable.map ({ fruits: [apples, oranges, mangoes]});
```

How do i delete one of the element of the array while maintaining immutability.

```
var newList = {fruits: [apples, oranges]};
```

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851147/best-way-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-inside-of-a-map-in-immutable-js

Comment: not really, and there is no map.filter in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var newList = fruitList.get('fruits').delete(fruitList.get('fruits').findIndex(fruit => fruit === 'mangoes'))
```